# Trigger inside of a touch/click event for iOS does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, datetime, mobile

I am developing a mobile application, and I want my user to click an image, and for that to open their device's native datetime picker application.

NB: this works fine for android - just not for iOS.

HTML:

```html
<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x" id="datetime_picker"></i>
<label id="new-incident-time-of-incident-label" class="label-datetime" data-field="IncidentDate" style="white-space: nowrap;"></label>
<input id="input" type="datetime-local" style="position: absolute; left: 9999px;"/>
```

As you can see from the above code, I'm throwing the input far off to the side, for it to stay in the DOM, but not be visible (I tried other things like `display: none`, `visibility: hidden`, but that caused other issues). It looks like this:

[image]

The `label` is there to present the value selected in the `input` when the user clicks the `i`-element.

So, maybe this seems a bit weird, but it works fine for android devices.
Not so much for iOS.

This is my JS:

```js
$("#datetime_picker").on("touchend", () => {

    $("#input").trigger("click");
});
```

I played around with combinations of `click`-, `touchend`-, `touchstart`-events, but to no avail.

Here is all of the JS-code, in case it is needed for reference (you never know...):

```js
const $input = $("#input");
let initDone = false;

function setValue(date) {
  $input.val(new XDate(date).toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm"));
  $("#new-incident-time-of-incident-label").text(new XDate(date).toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm"));
}

dsIncident.attachEvent("onDataLoaded", () => {
  if (initDone) {
    return;
  }
  initDone = true;
  const date = dsIncident.currentRow("IncidentDate");
  console.log("Initial date set:", date);
  setValue(date);
});

$("#input").on("input", () => {
  const date = new XDate($input.val())[0];
  console.log("Date changed:", date);
  dsIncident.currentRow("IncidentDate", date);
});

$("#datetime_picker").on("touchend", () => {

    $("#input").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: That's a misuse of a `label` to begin with. The label should be the "this is to be clicked" part here - clicking a label is _supposed to_ set focus on the correspondning input field. Use something else for your output.

Comment: Does the whole thing first of all work (on iOS), when you do _nothing_ to the input field, and just leave it in normal flow, without any additional formatting?

Comment: @Cbroe, if I leave the input in its "natural form", and hook it up to the <i> element, so that the <i> element receives the click, it won't work on iOS - but will work on android. Same as my solution presented above. Hiding or displacing the input makes no difference, as far as I can see.

Comment: @CBroe, as for your comment about the label intended to highlight its input; I didn't know of that, and will implement that for my code going forth. But that's relevant for the topmost label, not the bottom one.

Comment: _"Hiding or displacing the input makes no difference"_ - okay, but important to at least test that. (Sometimes stuff like this does not work _because_ the element was hidden or moved; a browser might for example try and orient the popup position on the position of the input field itself.)

Comment: You could perhaps try and position the input field so that the part of it that triggers the popup when clicked, gets to sit behind your "clock" icon that is supposed to trigger this? `pointer-events: none` on the icon itself (so that the click/tap can pass through it), and the input field itself "hidden" with `opacity: .01` or something? (Not `opacity: 0`, that often triggers issues with the element not "being interactable with" at all again.)

Comment: @CBroe I hate that I love hacky solutions like that. Lol.. it worked! Thanks! If you're not embarrassed to set it as a solution, i'll mark it as accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hiding or displacing the input makes no difference

Okay, but important to at least test that. Sometimes stuff like this does not work because the element was hidden or moved; a browser might for example try and orient the popup position on the position of the input field itself.

You could try and position the input field so that the part of it that triggers the popup when clicked, gets to sit behind your "clock" icon that is supposed to trigger this. `pointer-events: none` on the icon itself (so that the click/tap can pass through it), and the input field itself "hidden" with `opacity: .01` or something. (Not `opacity: 0`, that often triggers issues with the element not "being interactable with" at all again.)